# How to read checkbox value in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to get the value of checkbox - i.e `true` or `false`. But this is only returning me *Object Object*.

```
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> 
   <mat-checkbox [checked]="row.isDisabled" (change)="UpdateValue($event,row)">
   </mat-checkbox> 
</mat-cell>
```

In my TS, I have this:

```
UpdateValue(event:any, myStock: stock) {
  alert(event);
  ...
}
```

Does anyone know how I can get the value as true or false?

Comment: I tried that bug getting this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Answer (score 3):

Simply use:

```
UpdateValue(event:any,myStock: stock) {
   // ...
   console.log(event.checked);
}
```

Here's a working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/del-workspace) for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Just use ngModel

```
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> <mat-checkbox 
   [checked]="row.isDisabled" 
   [(ngmModel)]="checkValue"
   (change)="UpdateValue($event,row)"></mat-checkbox> </mat- 
    cell>


UpdateValue(event:any,myStock: stock) {
     alert(this.checkValue); 
 }
```